# Service is not running in some devices and unable to stop running service

Tags: service, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, location, location-services

I have location service implemented in my app that runs for every x minutes.
Service is started when the user logs in and whenever the app is killed and opened, I check to see if the service is running or not in OnStart().

In App.xaml.cs,
Code to stop service:

```
DependencyService.Get<IDeviceService>().StopLocationService();
```

Code to check if the service is running:

```
bool IsLocationServiceRunning = DependencyService.Get<IServiceRunning>().IsServiceRunning();
```

In DeviceService.cs:

```
public void StopLocationService()
    {
        try
        {
            Android.App.Application.Context.StopService(new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(LocationService)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.LogMessage("Error in StopLocationService(M): " + ex.Message, LogMessageType.error);
        }
    }
```

ServiceRunning.cs:

```
public bool IsServiceRunning()
    {
        try
        {
            ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
            Type serviceClass = typeof(LocationService);
            foreach (var service in manager.GetRunningServices(int.MaxValue))
            {
                if (service.Service.ClassName.EndsWith(typeof(LocationService).Name))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.LogMessage("Error in IsServiceRunning(M): ", LogMessageType.error);
            Utility.LogError(ex, LogMessageType.error);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Fisrt I'm stopping the service, and when I check the IsLocationService running, it still says true.

Any Idea how to stop a service?
I need to stop a service and start again in some scenarios.

thanks

Comment: ,Can you Log some infotmation for StopLocationService, when you stop this service, take a look if there are these information. Then you can confirm if you have stopped this service.

Comment: ok. can you check if this is the correct way to check if the service is running and stopping the service?

Comment: ,I think your service running and stopping are no problem.